# How to reduce GC caused by List.Contain() in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to reduce the GC in my Unity project,here is the following code, I want to know the reason.

Thank you guys a lot :)

here is the code I extract from a Demo,I'm using this data "Bineary Heap" structure to implement the Astar algorithm

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    Waypoint wp = new Waypoint();
    BinaryHeap<Waypoint> openls = new BinaryHeap<Waypoint>();
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
        {
            UnityEngine.Profiling.Profiler.BeginSample("contain");
            openls.Contains(wp);    
            UnityEngine.Profiling.Profiler.EndSample();
        }
    }

    public class BinaryHeap<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        private List<T> mHeap;

        public BinaryHeap() { this.mHeap = new List<T>(); }

        public void Insert(T data)
        {
            int size = mHeap.Count;
            mHeap.Add(data);
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return mHeap.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return mHeap.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public class Waypoint : IComparable<Waypoint>
    {
        public int id = 0;
        public int CompareTo(Waypoint p)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the progile report in Unity 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qirza.png)

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion it was causing a GC / boxing issue?

Comment: This is the only one script in my Unity project ,I use Unity BeginProfile to find this gc in Contain function

Comment: What _is_ this "GC problem" you're talking about? What exactly do you observe? Where do you pass a value type? Why is your compare method implemented like that?

Comment: If `openls.Contains` ends up calling `Enumerable.Contains`, then you would have to go look at the source code or disassembly to see where allocations are happening. For instance, if you pass no comparer to .Contains, it gets the default comparer. Does that allocate something? Also, since BinaryHeap doesn't implement IList or ICollection or anything, every time you do a .Contains, it will construct an enumerator because of `foreach`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks alot ,for what I said about  GC problem I add a image you can see, I'm want to figure out why GC happens, I mean pass a value type can lead boxing problems and cause GC, but I just pass a "waypoint "which I guess is a reference type ,but I still get a GC problem, this method is what I extracted from my company's project , If I made you confused ,I'm really sorry TAT

Comment: You should implement your own .Contains method then, in a manner that doesn't allocate anything. The LINQ Contains method, when called on an IEnumerable, will always construct an enumerator, which is a new object.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thanks a lot !! I guess I understand a little ,  I'm sorry because I'm still not sure how to implement my own Contains function

Comment: `public bool Contains(T value) { return mHeap.Contains(value); }`

Comment: The image still does not describe your "GC problem". So calling a method 400 times costs rougly 15 KB of memory, is that the problem? When asking for help, you need to be very verbose about what you expect and what you observe. A "GC problem" would for example mean that your memory usage keeps increasing per call, meaning you would be leaking unmanaged references, or something like that.

Comment: `return 1;` Can you tell us what you think that line of code does?

Comment: @mjwills My boss asked me to optimize our Company's demo about auto nabigation , I have to lower GC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class doesn't have a `Contains` method, which means that you're using LINQ's `Contains` extension method. That one has no idea that your class has a list inside - all it has is the `IEnumerable` interface, which means it needs to create an enumerator. The memory you're allocating is around 40B per call, which is probably this one object.

If you want to avoid that allocation, write your own `Contains` method. Since you're already using a list, you can simply call `Contains` on the list:

```
public bool Contains(T obj) => mHeap.Contains(obj);
```

As a side-note, boxing is not an effect here anyway - you're using a generic list class, so there would be no boxing even if you used a value type. That's the main reason why generics were added to C# in the first place (though they certainly have many useful functions beyond that).

Comment: I find a new problem, we know  mHeap.Contains() needs a lot of time ,which means the FPS of my Unity project is below 60FPS, is there a better way to balance  hign FPS and low GC?

Comment: How many points are in `mHeap` on average? Since `mHeap` is a list, `.Contains` will always do a sequential lookup. You might need to use a more clever data structure, such as a Hashset or similar.

Comment: yes ,there are many points in mHeap , If I can't balance high FPS and lower GC , maybe I have to think about another data structure , thanks alot!

Comment: @wutoby You named your class "binary heap". Presumably, you were trying to implement a binary heap, rather than a linear list; a well-balanced binary heap could cut down the search time to about log N, which may be more along what you need. A hash set can even give you the answer in constant time, and would usually be preferable if you need to search much more often than change the set. You need to balance your requirements and pick a solution that fits best :)

Comment: @wutoby Assuming a constant set, GC isn't a factor anyway. You're reading, which can be done without any allocations. If you implement `Waypoint` properly, this is as simple as using `HashSet<Waypoint>` instead of `List<Waypoint>`.

Comment: @Luaan yes, I'm using this data structure to implement the Astar algorithm ,so I have to make a balance